# How can I set the cursor to 'grabbing' when panning in react-flow?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, addeventlistener, react-flow

I am using react-flow and the user can pan around by clicking and dragging on the background. I would like the cursor to be 'grab' when hovering over the background, and the cursor to be 'grabbing' while the user has the mouse button down and is dragging/panning around.

##### What is working:

I have been able to get the cursor to be 'grab' while hovering over the background by setting the style on `ReactFlow` like so:

```
<ReactFlow
      style={{ cursor: "grab" }}
      ...
```

##### What is not working:

I can't get the cursor to be 'grabbing' while the mouse button is held down over the background.

##### What I've tried:

I've tried setting the cursor conditionally based on a `mouseDown` state variable like this: `style={{ cursor: mouseDown ? 'grabbing' : 'grab' }}`

But for some reason the mouseDown/mouseUp events do not fire with the mouse over the background, even though they fire when clicking on other elements. Here's how I've tried to do that:

```
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseDown = () => {
    setMouseDown(true);
    console.log('mouse down');
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setMouseDown(false);
    console.log('mouse up');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, []);
```

Here's a codesandbox example where the cursor is correctly set to 'grab', but does not get set to 'grabbing' (see the `src/Flow.js` file):

[image: Edit hopeful-ellis-nr675y]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead add listener to window how bout using react flow's event api instead? your code work perfectly if u doing right click. maybe react flow's do stopPropagation() for left mouse

```
<ReactFlow
  style={{ cursor: mouseDown ? "grabbing" : "grab" }}
  nodes={nodes}
  edges={edges}
  onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
  onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
  onConnect={onConnect}
  onInit={onInit}
  fitView

  onMoveStart={handleMouseDown} 
  onMoveEnd={handleMouseUp}
>
```

Comment: `onMove` fires a million times, but `onMoveStart` works great